# Citrix/XenApp Content Redirection from within Application

Tags: ms-access, vba, citrix, xenapp

I have the situation where we're using XenApp to run a Access 2010 app, as the client PC's aren't capable of doing so.  The app generates Word documents and to avoid printing issues I would like to see if its possible to use XenApp's content redirection so that when opening a document its opened on the client machine?

I've got published content redirection working, but all attempts a initiating it from within our Access app just loads the server side Word.

At the moment I've tried `ShellExecute` and UNC paths and File URI's.  Also tried Wscript.Shell object and I also tried creating a HTML page with a HREF and opening that.

Is what I'm attempting possible? It would be good to know as then I can just concentrate on alternative solutions.

I've got a vague feeling that a solution could be in using an alternative hWnd in ShellExecute, ie if I could more closely simulate a user opening a file manually, the content redirection would kick in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use content redirection for this, see:

http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/xenapp6-w2k8-admin/ps-pub-content-redirect-server-task-v2.html

Content redirection is purely for web links, specifically the following types of links are supported:

- HTTP (Hypertext Transfer Protocol)
- HTTPS (Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol)
- RTSP (Real Player and QuickTime)
- RTSPU (Real Player and QuickTime)
- PNM (Legacy Real Player)
- MMS (Microsoft Media Format)

Comment: thanks ever so much for this, this is what we were thinking, but wanted confirmation.